# Add SSL for web application without domain registered

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, https, windows-server-2016

I have a .NET winform application that connects to a remote database on a VPS (windows 2016 server), the connection is made through OpenVpn
because it was necessary for certain functions to be used on the mobile phone as well, an extension was made with Angular + .NET Core, as there is no domain, access is made
through the browser directly based on the IP,the authentication is done with JWT. The browser shows in the bar the exclamation mark and in details ‘Your connection site is not secure’
The application is not necessarily public, the number of users is small <10. I don't know SSH and I said to ask you for an opinion, can the web application be secured without the need for a domain? Is there anything free?

thank you

Comment: Impossible. HTTPS requires a server certificate, and you must have a domain registered and then be qualified to request such a certificate.

Comment: ok,it is also possible for me to generate the certificate and install it to client?

Comment: After registering the domain name and have control over its DNS records, you can request certificates in several ways (via commercial Certificate Authorities, Let's Encrypt and so on). Use a search engine to learn more.